# SQL Server / Remove duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

**I have a table with 3 million records**. The table looks like that :

```
id          phones
----------- -----------------
0           1234; 5897;
1           0121; 7875; 5455;
2           0121; 5455; 7875;
3           999;
4           0121;
5           5455; 0121;
```

Records with id 1, 2, 4 & 5 are duplicates. I would like to keep the only record with the highest id and the longest phone string.

So in my example, after running the query, my table should be :

```
id          phones
----------- -----------------
0           1234; 5897;
2           0121; 5455; 7875;
3           999;
```

How would I accomplish this?

NB : there is no blank space in phone strings.

Comment: oh dear! that's a poor schema.

Comment: Though actually the task of finding exact duplicates wouldn't be much easier if properly designed in first normal form.

Comment: really? Seems a lot easier to me.

Comment: @MitchWheat - You'd need some hairy exact relational division query and it would probably just be quicker (better performing across all possible data distributions) and easier to use `XML PATH` on the normalised data and compare the concatenated strings. [Similar question about finding recipes with identical ingredients](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/45302/3690)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should be a good starting point;

you will need to create a 2 temp tables.

one that will hold the id(column Id), one that will hold the phones(column Id, Phone). so this will be a one to many.

then what you need to do is to insert in these 2 tables the whole original table

when this is done, start sorting/comparing result to reconstruct the filtered result.

so here is a demo; (this code is not ***optimized*** but work)

```
declare @AllPhones table (id int, phones varchar(max))

insert into @AllPhones select 0, '1234; 5897;'
insert into @AllPhones select 1, '0121; 7875; 5455;'
insert into @AllPhones select 2, '0121; 5455; 7875;'
insert into @AllPhones select 3, '999;'
insert into @AllPhones select 4, '0121;'
insert into @AllPhones select 5, '5455; 0121;'
insert into @AllPhones select 6, '222;'
insert into @AllPhones select 7, '888;'
insert into @AllPhones select 8, '222; 888;'
insert into @AllPhones select 9, '888; 222;'


select * from @AllPhones

declare @IdPhone table (id int, done bit)
declare @Phone table (id int, phone varchar(max), insertOrder int)

insert into @IdPhone
select id, 0
from   @AllPhones

declare @Id int
declare @ConcatPhone varchar(max)

declare @idx int       
declare @slice varchar(max)
declare @insertOrder int

while exists(select * from @IdPhone where done=0)
begin
    select top 1 @Id = ap.id
               , @ConcatPhone = ap.phones
    from @IdPhone ip inner join @AllPhones ap on ip.id = ap.id
    where done=0 

    select @idx = 1
    select @insertOrder = 1       
    if len(@ConcatPhone)> 0 and @ConcatPhone is not null
    begin
        while @idx!= 0       
        begin       
            set @idx = charindex(';',@ConcatPhone)       
            if @idx!=0       
                set @slice = left(@ConcatPhone,@idx - 1)       
            else       
                set @slice = @ConcatPhone       

            if(len(@slice)>0)
                insert into @Phone(Id, phone,insertOrder) values(@Id, rtrim(ltrim(@slice)),@insertOrder)       

            set @ConcatPhone = right(@ConcatPhone,len(@ConcatPhone) - @idx)       
            if len(@ConcatPhone) = 0 break       

            select @insertOrder = @insertOrder+1 
        end   
    end

    update @IdPhone 
    set done=1 
    where Id = @Id
end

declare @UniquePhone table (id int, c int, phone varchar(max),insertOrder int, done int)

insert into @UniquePhone
    select p.id
         , (select top 1 count(pCount.id) from @phone pCount where pCount.id=p.id) as t
         , p.phone
         ,p.insertOrder
         ,0
    from @phone p
    group by p.id, p.phone, p.insertOrder

while exists(select * from @UniquePhone where done=0)
begin
    select top 1 @Id = up.id
    from @UniquePhone up 
    where done=0 
    order by c desc
           , id desc

    delete from @UniquePhone 
    where id <> @id and phone in (select phone from @UniquePhone pp where pp.id=@id)

    print @id

    update @UniquePhone 
    set done=1 
    where Id = @Id
end

select FinalTable.id,
       ltrim(rtrim(FinalTable.Phones)) As Phones
from(select distinct up2.id, 
           (select up1.phone + '; ' as [text()]
            from @UniquePhone up1
            where up1.id = up2.id
            order by up1.id, insertOrder
            for XML PATH ('')) Phones
     from @UniquePhone up2) [FinalTable]
```

Comment: You're leaving finding exact duplicate groups in the `phones(column Id, Phone)` as an exercise for the reader?

Comment: Well you haven't answered how at all. You've advised him to restructure the table then just been hand wavy on the tricky bit!

Comment: @Fredou : Thanks for this code. This works fine with the values in our example. But i can't get it work with values taken from my test table. [Here is a screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/b7y9a6e6j/).

Comment: @Fredou, it works fine ! Excepted that the output phones are [in the wrong order](http://postimg.org/image/woqzi8fjt/). Is it possible to replace the old table by the new one ? Many thanks !

Comment: @Korplex, that was an easy fix, could test it again? :-)

Comment: Any tips to optimize this code ? I ran the query on my 3m+ records table 8hours ago. And it's not still finished...

Comment: @Korplex i would create proper table with proper index instead of using table variables. after that, i don't have the source table so i cannot really tell.